# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p" Problem

Tags: java, jvm, jetty

I have an issue with trying to pass the `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"` command into my jvm args.

I am using Jetty7, and have this within the start.ini file.  On start up it give me the error below. This is with jre /jre1.6.0_03l64

> Starting Jetty: STARTED Jetty Tue Apr 26 09:54:26 EDT 2011
>   Unrecognized option: -9
>   Could not create the Java virtual machine.

The start.ini file is as below.

```
#===========================================================
# If the arguements in this file include JVM arguments
# (eg -Xmx512m) or JVM System properties (eg com.sun.???),
# then these will not take affect unless the --exec
# parameter is included or if the output from --dry-run
# is executed like:
#   eval $(java -jar start.jar --dry-run)
#
# Below are some recommended options for Sun's JRE
#-----------------------------------------------------------
  --exec
# -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
  -Xmx4096m
  -Xmn512m
  -DLABEL=PROD_APP
  -verbose:gc
  -Xloggc:/export/opt/prod_app/logs/gc.log
  -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
# -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
  -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
  -XX:+PrintGCDetails
  -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
# -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags
# -XX:+DisableExplicitGC
# -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
# -XX:ParallelCMSThreads=2
# -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
# -XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection
# -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=80
```

Commenting the line out jetty will start fine with no issue. However we really need to add this arg due to memory leak with the system to prevent further damage if our process falls over.

Would anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here or how I can fix this?

Comment: I had problems with something similar as well but it was in my own batch/bash files. Maybe jetty puts his own quotes around everything in the .ini file. You might try with single quotes (') instead?

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't work... It says `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="<cmd args>;<cmd args>" Run user-defined commands when an OutOfMemoryError is first thrown. (Introduced in 1.4.2 update 12, 6)` http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Answer (score 28):

In Java version 8u92 the VM arguments

- `-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError`
- `-XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError`

were added, see the [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u92-relnotes-2949471.html).

> **ExitOnOutOfMemoryError**
>   When you enable this option, the JVM exits on the
>   first occurrence of an out-of-memory error. It can be used if you
>   prefer restarting an instance of the JVM rather than handling out of
>   memory errors.
>
> **CrashOnOutOfMemoryError**
>   If this option is enabled, when an
>   out-of-memory error occurs, the JVM crashes and produces text and
>   binary crash files.

Enhancement Request: [JDK-8138745](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8138745) (parameter naming is wrong though  [JDK-8154713](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154713), `ExitOnOutOfMemoryError` instead of `ExitOnOutOfMemory`)

Answer (score 4):

Running as a hadoop option I run in to the same issues.
This was the answer:

```
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'
```

Here is stdout on OOM:

```
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 11902"...
```

I also tried:

```
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='"kill -9 %p"'
```

It started, but on OOM it

```
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill' '-9' '%p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill' '-9' '1164"...
```

But STDERR has:
sh: kill -9 1164: command not found

These Wouldn't even start:

```
'-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p'
"-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p"
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
```

Comment: I opened a bug for this here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=408904

This should have been reported as a bug years ago and we could have gotten it addressed earlier.

Comment: The error `sh: kill -9 1164: command not found` is telling you what is important.  That the executable passed to sh is `kill -9 1164` (note, this is name of the executable that it is trying to run).  Proof: if you type something like `$ blargfish -9 1164` on your command line right now, you get `blarghfish: command not found`.  Notice that the command line arguments are not present in the error message.

Answer (score 4):

The single quote version should work fine in jetty >9.0.4 now.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=408904

Answer (score 4):

I've run through this problem pretty recently. I have solved it by setting the option into the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable. This variable is documented [by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/envvars.html) and you must `export` this variable on you shell commands and the `JVM` will append it to the arguments.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to quote the whole option, like this:

```
  "-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p"
```

Comment: If i put quote around the entire option then id does not appear in the actual process args, i would have expected to see it in here. Although it does start up which is positive. //1526 1506 99 04:51 pts/2 00:00:05 /usr/java/jre1.6.0_03l64/bin/java -Xmx4096m -Xmn512m -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/export/opt/atdirect_dev/logs/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -Djetty.home=/export/opt/PROD_APP –Dprod_app.connection-client.cfg=/export/opt/PROD_APP/lib/PROD/prod.connection-client.cfg -DLABEL=PROD_APP

Answer (score 3):

You need to use 
`-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/bin/kill -9 %p`

Also if you want to test the changes, you can echo a message before you kill it.

`-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/bin/date; /bin/echo custom message;/bin/kill -9 %p`

Answer (score 2):

I found this option in a script and wanted to find out more about it, and google brought me here. In the script in question the option is given as

```
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='"kill -9 %p"'
```

So the command is double quoted, and the option value is single quoted. This isn't one of the forms shown in the other answers, so maybe it will do what you want it to?

Answer (score 2):

The following works

```
java -classpath $CLASSPATH "-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=touch 'worker.oome'"  $JVM_ARGS $MAIN
```

Most of the provided answers do not work.

However.. if you want to put it in e.g. the $JVM_ARGS variable you are in for a world of pain.

Answer (score 1):

In a recent release of Java 8 (update 92), you now have the option to use `ExitOnOutOfMemoryError` option.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u92-relnotes-2949471.html

Answer (score 0):

I've even tried embedding a space using %20 but that was taken literally. So, when it got a OOM, it failed saying the command (with the embedded %20) could not be found. Crazy, I know, but was worth a try... :)

Maybe we're supposed to use the actual < and > like the Sun docs?! :P I'll try it... :)

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of invoking `kill`, run a shell script that invokes `kill` with the pid passed as an argument (you would still have a space, but no -9 flag).

e.g. `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='/path/killdash9.sh %p'`

If you still can't have the space, maybe try having the shell script find the pid associated with that Jetty instance? Quite a hack, but it might work.

Answer (score 0):

the correct syntax is to escape quotes(")

```
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=\"kill -9 %p\"
```