# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="<cmd args>" not working in Windows?

Tags: java

My goal is to execute a script (Windows batch file) when an java.lang.OutOfMemoryError is thrown, as per the option described in the [Hotspot VM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)

```
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="<cmd args>; <cmd args>"
```

I cannot get a script, or any other process, to execute when a OutOfMemoryError is thrown.  First I tried launching cmd.exe and specifying the path to the script, I modified where the doublequotes went, used frontslashes instead of backslashes, used double-backslashes.  I've abandoned slashes and quotes altogether and tried simple .exes the live in the working directory or on the PATH.  Nothing works.

I can't get any executable to even *attempt* to run.  By using [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) I've determined that the JVM isn't even looking for an executable with the name I specify, much less trying to launch it.

I know I have the option specified correctly in the JVM params because it complains if I deliberately insert a typo.  I'm trying things like the following:

```
java -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=myprocess.exe com.mycompany.SimulateOome
java -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="myprocess.exe" com.mycompany.SimulateOome
java "-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=myprocess.exe" com.mycompany.SimulateOome
```

Which produces the expected stack trace to stdout/err.

It could be my test class.  My current version simply throws java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.  I've also simulated a more organic OOME by allocating a large array.  Neither works.

I'm using JDK 1.6.0_38 on Windows 2003/2008 but also tried JDK 1.7.

**EDIT:**

The test class was at fault. Neither simply throwing the exception, nor a simple huge array allocation, will cause the OOME handler to fire, despite otherwise successfully throwing the OOME. See below for Perception's OutOfMem class that does trigger the OOME handler. After sorting that out, the syntax is easy, and the quotes can either surround the entire option, or just the part after the equals. For a Windows shell script, one can use:

```
java "-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c c:\scripts\my_oome_handler.bat" com.mycompany.MyClass
```

or

```
java -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c c:\scripts\my_oome_handler.bat" com.mycompany.MyClass
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p" Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792049/xxonoutofmemoryerror-kill-9-p-problem)

Comment: Saw that one and don't think it's a dupe.  Again I tried every possible combination of quotes and even no quotes, and it's not a problem passing arguments, it's a problem trying to get the JVM to do anything at all when OOME occurs.

Comment: is this in PowerShell or Dos, because there are [quoting issues in PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6351739/254477).

Comment: It's in straight cmd.exe, no PowerShell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It could be my test class. My current version simply throws
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. I've also simulated a more organic OOME
>   but allocating a large array. Neither works.

I tested this out and it does indeed seem to be the case. Still looking for a solid explanation why, but using Java 7:

```
public class OutOfMem {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final List<byte[]> segments = new ArrayList<byte[]>(64000);

        final int size = 6400000;

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
            segments.add(new byte[size * i]);
        }

        for (final byte[] data : segments) {
            final int dataSize = data.length;
            System.out.printf("Segment [size=%s]\n", dataSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Running above with `java "-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=ls" OutOfMem` works just fine (executes the ls command). However, with this class:

```
public class OutOfMem2 {
        public static void main(final String[] args) throws Throwable {
                throw new OutOfMemoryError("Fake OOME");
        }
}
```

Running `java "-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=ls" OutOfMem2` spits out the exception stacktrace, but does not actually fire off the OOME handler.

Comment: Interesting.  My other method was "long[] l = new long[Integer.MAX_VALUE];" but I ran into the same issues.  I may have missed some tests when using that method though so I'll re-run them with this more "organic" method.

Comment: Perception is right, it's the test class at fault.  Neither simply throwing the exception, nor the array allocation in my previous comment will cause the OOME handler to fire.  Perception's OutOfMem class does.  After sorting that out, the syntax is easy, and the quotes can either surround the entire option, or just the part after the equals.  For a Windows shell script, one can use:  "-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c c:\scripts\my_oome_handler.bat"

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried wrapping the arguments in quotes?

```
java -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="myprocess.exe SimulateOome"
```

Also make sure you myprocess.exe is either accessible through PATH or instead give the full path to the process.

Comment: In my example, SimulateOome is the class (SimulateOome.class) and the exception is thrown in the main method.  But to answer the intent of your question:  yes, I've tried wrapping arguments in quotes.