# Why is my environment variable incorrectly processed as a JVM option?

Tags: java, bash, environment-variables, jvm-arguments

I want to use an environment variable as a JVM option when executing `java -jar`.

The command I want to execute it:

```
java -XX:onOutOfMemory='echo test' -jar foo.jar
```

When I run the above command as is, the jar will run.

(If you don't have the foo.jar, you will get an `Error: Unable to access jarfile foo.jar` error. But this still means that the option gets used correctly).

But when I create an environment variable containing the JVM option, and run the command using that variable.

```
OOM="-XX:onOutOfMemory='echo test'"
java $OOM -jar foo.jar
```

Than I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class test'
```

It seems like the `java` command is ignoring the quotes around 'echo test'.

After looking for similar questions [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5792049/2201792) and [on other websites](http://www.91r.net/ask/5801362.html), I tried various variations of using quotes:

```
OOM="-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=\"echo test\""
OOM='-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="echo test"'
OOM=-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="echo test"
```

But they all result in the same error.

[An article from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) concerning JVM options, mentions using a semicolon:

```
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="<cmd args>; <cmd args>"
```

But the purpose of the semicolon is to separate multiple commands, not command and arguments. So this does not fix my problem.

Does anybody know how I can correctly move the `-XX:onOutOfMemory='echo test'` option into an environment variable?

Comment: The 'echo test' doesn't really have a purpose. I used it as an example. The actual command I want to execute is: 'kill -9 %p'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running java, you should quote `$OOM`

Example:

```
java "$OOM" -jar foo.jar
```

See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/43400) on Unix stackexchange for why this is needed.

Comment: I can't believe it was this simple! Quoting the variable did the trick. I'll also take a look at the answer you referenced, it seems to contain a lot of useful information.