# Kill/Term java on out of memory

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory

I wrote the following simple program:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        new Thread(() -> {
            try{
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch(Exception ignored){ }
            throw new OutOfMemoryError("BOOM!");
        }).start();

        while(true){
            System.out.println("Doing some job...");
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(Exception ignored){ }
        }

    }
}
```

Now I run this with options `java -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p" Main` and expect that the program receives `SIGKILL` the error thrown. But it ends up printing `Doing some job...` even after `OutOfMemoryError` was thrown:

```
Doing some job...
Doing some job...
Doing some job...
Doing some job...
Doing some job...
Doing some job...
Doing some job...
Doing some job...
Doing some job...
Doing some job...
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: BOOM!
        at Main.lambda$main$0(Main.java:11)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Doing some job...
Doing some job...
Doing some job...
Doing some job...
Doing some job...
Doing some job...
Doing some job...
Doing some job...
Doing some job...
Doing some job...
Doing some job...
```

What's wrong with this?

I'm on `java 1.8.0_66`

I tried to do `java -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p' Main` and `java "-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p" Main` but it still keep working...

I also tried to check it and execute `sudo java -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="echo 233 > /root/oom" Main` and expected `/root/oom` will contain `223`, but no file was created. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p" Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792049/xxonoutofmemoryerror-kill-9-p-problem)

Comment: @Edwardth Just tried it with `java "-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p" Main` and `java -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p' Main` and it didn't work...

Comment: @Edwardth I tried all of the examples and no one works...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError` works only for OutOfMemoryErrors thrown by JVM itself.

User-generated OutOfMemoryErrors does not differ from any other regular Throwable, and they are not treated specially by JVM.